# Simple example can't access scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to learn AngularJS, and going through an older tutorial I have built out a simple app.  It has an index.html and two partial views which are loaded via ui-router.  I know it's not separated into different files -- this is a learning project only.

The problem is that $scope does not seem to be available in View1 or in its called JS function , so `ng-repeat` doesn't seem to find anything to display, and `addCustomer` cannot see $scope.newCustomer.name.  I am sure that I am missing something simple.

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <title></title>
  <script src="js/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <!-- your app's js -->
  <script>

 var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ui.router']); // [] is for dependencies

// routes
demoApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  var nameState = {
    name: 'name',
    url: '/view1',
    controller: 'SimpleController',
    templateUrl: 'partials/View1.html'
  }

  var cityState = {
    name: 'city',
    url: '/view2',
    controller: 'SimpleController',
    templateUrl: 'partials/View2.html'
  }

  $stateProvider.state(nameState);
  $stateProvider.state(cityState);

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/view1');
});

 // controller

demoApp.controller("SimpleController", function ( $scope, $log ) {
    $scope.log = $log;

    $scope.customers = [{name: 'John Doe', city:'New York'}, 
                        {name: 'Jake Smith', city:'Atlanta'}, 
                        { name: 'Jane Doe', city:'San Francisco'}];


    $scope.addCustomer = function () {
      $log.log("Add customer");
      $scope.customers.push(
        {name: $scope.newCustomer.name, city: $scope.newCustomer.city}
        );
    };
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <!-- placeholder for views inserted by ui-router -->
    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**View1.html**:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>View 1</h2>
  Name: <input type="text" ng-model="filter.name" /> You entered:  {{filter.name}}
  <div class="container">
    <h3> Loop </h3>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="cust in $scope.customers | filter:filter.name">{{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.city }}</li>
    </ul>
    <br /> Customer Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.name" />
    <br /> Customer City:
    <input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.city" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <button ng-click="addCustomer()">Add Customer</button>
  </div>
  <a href="#/view2">Switch to View 2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only

```
ng-repeat="cust in customers"
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to specify $scope in the html:

```
ng-repeat="cust in customers"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
<li ng-repeat="cust in customers">
```

you dont need to mention `$scope.customers`

Answer (score 1):

try this (remove "$scope.") :

```
ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:filter.name"
```

instead of :

```
ng-repeat="cust in $scope.customers | filter:filter.name"
```